# Sensor data timestamps using VictoriaMetrics

Tags: victoriametrics

I am trying to figure out how to record timestamped sensor data to an instance of VictoriaMetrics. I have an embedded controller with a sensor that is read once per second. I would like VictoriaMetrics to poll the controller once a minute, and log all 60 readings with their associated timestamps into the TSDB.

I have the server and client running, and measuring system metrics is easy, but I can't find an example of how to get a batch of sensor readings to be reported by the embedded client, nor have I been able to figure it out from the docs.

Any insights are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

VictoriaMetrics supports data ingestion via [various protocols](https://victoriametrics.github.io/#how-to-import-time-series-data). All these protocols support batching, i.e. multiple measurements can be sent in a single request. So you can choose the best suited protocol for inserting batches of collected measurements into VictoriaMetrics. For example, if [Prometheus text exposition format](https://victoriametrics.github.io/#how-to-import-data-in-prometheus-exposition-format) is selected for data ingestion, then a batch of metrics could look like the following:

```
measurement_name{optional="labels"} value1 timestamp1
...
measurement_name{optional="labels"} valueN timestampN
```

Comment: I see, this is a 'push' from the client. I can work with that. Is there a way to do it with a scrape?

Comment: It is possible to export multiple samples for the same metric in Prometheus text exposition format as described above and then configure VictoriaMetrics to scrape these samples. See https://victoriametrics.github.io/#how-to-scrape-prometheus-exporters-such-as-node-exporter

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept an answer once I've got this working.

Answer (score 0):

VictoriaMetrics can poll (scrape) metrics from the configured address via HTTP. It expects application to return metrics value in the exposition text format. The exposition text format is compatible with Prometheus, so its [libraries](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/clientlibs/) for different languages will be compatible with VictoriaMetrics as well.

There is also a how-to guide for instrumenting golang application to expose metrics and scrape via VictoriaMetrics [here](https://victoriametrics.medium.com/how-to-monitor-go-applications-with-victoriametrics-c04703110870). It describes the monitoring basics for any service or application.